# Visual Studio Intellisense not work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, intellisense

I have one problem. When I press ctrl + space the Intellisense window will not show, but it works! I can chose any word by arrows press enter and then it one will appear, but the windows with this words not show. Some times it showed sometimes no. This problem occurs only when I am working with TFS project.

This is enabled 
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Auto list members
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->General->Parameter information
Tools->Options->Text Editor->C#->Intellisense->Show completion list after a character is typed

***UPD***
I have just committed changes, and the same problem occurred on colleges PC).

Comment: Any addin (like Resharper) installed?

Comment: You say "I have just committed changes."  Does this mean the colleague wasn't seeing the problem until your changes were committed?  Is this purely intellisense on classes/members in your code, or is this for all intellisense?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Only for one my project. Posible Problem was in solution file. in this lines: {GlobalSection(PowerDesigner) = preSolution
  HasSWS = 1
 EndGlobalSection } I have deleted it, Intellisence is working fine now

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit old, but today, a colleague faced the same problem : intellisense did not work, neither than outlining.
He also had the line `{GlobalSection(PowerDesigner) = preSolution HasSWS = 1 EndGlobalSection }` in one of ours *.slns.

When he delete this line, intellisense work...better, but the outlining did work.
As it work pretty well on my computer, we found the only difference was a plugin : PowerDesigner from Sybase.
Without this plugin, intellisense and outlining work well again.

This was installed silently with another Sybase's product.